# Run bash command when spaces and '`/\<>?&| are filtered?

Tags: injection, bash

I have some PHP code that run bash commands, and it has a bug that may make it vulnerable to remote code execution.

The executed command would be `$(id)`, but if I execute any other command like `ls -la` the space is automatically replaced with `-`. I checked the source as well and I found that in addition to spaces, the following chars are filtered: `` '`/\<>?&| ``.

How can I bypass the filter and execute a command like `wget link`?

[Live demo.](https://pastebin.com/raw/1MfR6aic)

Answer (score 4):

If spaces are filtered but not tabs, just use a tab. If both are filtered but `$` isn't, you can use `${IFS}`.

If you can do command substitutions and spaces, it may help to use various `printf` format specifiers, `tr` with ranges and `eval` to reach forbidden characters.

Comment: printf runs as string .
cant bypass with it, do you have any live demo?

Comment: @user2444995: I think the StackExchange formatting ate some of your comment. Please use a pair of backticks ` to protect your special characters. (Anders fixed your question, but your comment seems to miss characters as well)

Comment: @user2444995 For example, with the characters you have, `printf${IFS}-v${IFS}bs${IFS}%q${IFS}"$IFS";bs=${bs:3:1}` sets the variable `bs` to a backslash.